# Flip test and control group in causal inference to get sufficient sample sizes for synthetic control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, causality, design-based-inference

There was supposed to be a **buy-one-get-one (BOGO) promotion** for sneakers at **5,000 stores**. Unfortunately, a glitch happened, and **100 of the stores did NOT get the memo** about the BOGO promotion, so they continued to sell the shoes at the usual prices. The other 4,900 stores did get the memo, and sold more shoes than usual because of the promotion.

As far as I can tell, **the glitch happened randomly**; there is no discernible pattern to the 100 stores that suffered the glitch.

I am using **causal inference** to determine how the BOGO promotion affected revenue. The usual routine would be to treat the 4,900 stores with the promotion as the test stores. However, I am using **synthetic control** to match multiple control stores to each test store and build a regression model for the treatment effect; **this usually requires more control stores than test stores**. *What I have is the exact opposite*; there are far more test stores (4,900) than control stores (100).

Here is my question: **Can I just "flip" the label and call the 100 stores the test stores instead?**

According to this argument, the resulting estimate would simply have the opposite sign of the true effect.

*This "**feels**" wrong*, because the control stores should be the ones that remained constant from the pre-glitch to the post-glitch timeframe. However, I can't come up with any good argument against this.

In experimental design, I would always call the group that received the treatment as the "experimental group", and the group that did NOT receive the treatment as the "control group". Flipping the labels feels wrong.